# firstOrCreate continuous insert new entry

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

i run

```
php artisan make:model Models/Test -m
```

create migrate file

```
Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->double('longitude', 9, 4);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Run migrate and edit Model

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Test extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['longitude'];
     //
}
```

when i run

```
$marker = Test::firstOrCreate([
    'longitude' => floatval(19.9276),
]);
echo $marker->id;
```

I see new entry added to db all the time.

When i change column type to varchar issue doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

you are using it wrong, if you want to use the firstOr method you have to give a value to check for existing. the first array is for values to search for existing the other one is for the new values:

```
    $marker = Test::firstOrCreate(
search values ->
 [
    'longitude' => floatval(19.9276),
 ],
 [
new values ->
 ]

);
echo $marker->id;
```

hope this helps

Comment: I already try, but like manual say
"If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the attributes from the first parameter, along with those in the optional second parameter."

If i change column data type to varchar, it work like indeed

Comment: if you dont want to chenge the type of the column then u can add the id of the exsiting item as a hiddin input in you'r request and then make the search value with it. I think that it would work with the id.

Comment: yep, i can change column type, also i can manually check the data already exists, but i want to known why function dedicated for this don't work